# .htaccess conditions - OR statement

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

What I have is a code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*\.php)$    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*\.html)$
```

However it doesn't work, because I think it checks if file extension is .php AND .htm which is impossible... How to change this so it'll work for .php OR .html?

Answer (score 5):

The following will ensure the conditions are joined with a logical OR:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*\.php)$  [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*\.html)$
```

I would recommend the following as slightly optimized - It ensure it strictly the extension (end) and the fielname capture can be done with your RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$  [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.html$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*\.php|html)$
```

Comment: The regex should be `^(.*\.(php|html))$`, otherwise the whole filename is being tested against `^(.*\.php)$` or `^(html)$`.