# OR statement in .htaccess file for RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, url

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597257/htaccess-conditions-or-statement) where they asked how to use the `OR` in `RewriteCond`statement. But, I need to know how to write the `RewriteRule` for both cases.
Basically, we have both `.html` and `.php` files on our website (only one extension is used for a filename). On accessing the URL through the browser, every URL should rewrite itself without their respective extensions.

This is the code I tried. Doesn't work at all. Kindly help.

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC] [OR] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$  [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.html$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.html
```

Edit: This is a straightforward method I tried which actually worked as intended. However, a problem arose when I tried to link the `validate.php` file in the `action` attribute of a form. It got redirected to `example.com/validate` and didn't work. On our other sites, the redirection to `example.com/validate` works as intended, where we only had `.php` files.

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You don't need an OR between two conditions; you have two separate cases, that should be _handled_ separately as well. What https://stackoverflow.com/a/4908133/1427878 shows, only done twice, once for each possible case.

Comment: I previously did a different version where I wrote the rules separately for both versions. It worked. Except when I linked a `.php` file to the `action='validate.php` in a form, it got redirected to `example.com/validate` and didn't work. The irony is, that it actually works on all of our other sites, where we only use `.php` files.

Comment: When you make a redirect with status code 301/302, the browser will follow that up with a _GET_ request, so you loose all your POST parameters at that point. Your form action should be corrected to `action='validate` to begin with, so that this external redirect is not necessary any more.

Comment: Wow. Turns out I had all the answers with me and didn't execute them well. Your comment helped me put the pieces in the order. 
For anyone facing this issue, have two separate rules, check the `action='validate'`  to be free of the `.php` extension and check if you have called the URL of your current page without the `.php` extension in the `validate.php`  (if called for some purpose) as well.

Answer (score 1):

See below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The first `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` checks if the requested URL maps to an existing directory or file. If it does, no further rewriting is done ([L] flag).

The next set checks if a `.html` file exists for the requested URL (minus the extension). If it does, it internally rewrites to that file.

The last set does the same but for `.php` files.